# JwtDecoder no longer exists in springsecurity6

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have run into trouble with upgrading to spring security core 6.1 and my filter chain is lacking a decoder for jwt.  The problem is the only class the jwt.decoder() function takes in, JwtDecoder, is no longer a supported class.

Right now I have changed it to look like the following:

```
  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable).authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.anyRequest().permitAll())
            .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth->oauth.jwt(jwt->jwt.decoder()));
    return http.build();
  }
```

and it used to look like the below block before the switch from spring security oauth2 to spring security 6

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
  }
```

I don't believe i should need the resource server at all but without it, I receive a "principalName cannot be empty error"

Need help getting the new one to work just as the old one did.  I want to accept all requests.

Comment: why not just read the JWT-chapter in the docs? https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-sansboot

Comment: I did, and it keeps saying to use JWT decoder....which does not exist anymore.

Comment: i have no idea what you are talking about, you are VERY unclear. the function does not take in a `class` it takes in something that implements the interface `JwtDecoder`. You have not posted anything about your code, all your question is basically saying is that "something" isnt working. Insert what your code looks like before, what it is you want it to do. What you are trying to get working because right now you are explaining nothing.

Comment: read it multiple times over, for days before i asked this question, and it does not help at all.
only difference between old code and my change is this one file that only has the security filter chain in it.  we switched to spring security core 6 from spring security oauth and the chain stopped working, i put an update above to show what it was before

Comment: it says right here how to expose a decoder, right here https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-decoder-bean its right there, in the link i posted the documentation explains exactly everything you need to do, and if something is unclear about the documentation, you ask about the docs and we will explain them. Stack overflow is not a forum, its a Q&A site, meaning you ask one well researched question and get one answer. And i have reported your comment

Comment: your comments have been reported, i have linked you exactly how to solve the problem, what you do with that information is up to you. I had no obligation to try to help you but still i did. So good luck with your problem, you are now on your own.

Answer (score 1):

`JwtDecoder` is still supported and you can find it here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-oauth2-jose

If you are using Maven, you can add it to your project:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

For Gradle:

```
        implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose:6.1.0'
```

Comment: yeah for some reason it took a while for my intellij to register that the dependency was there.  Kept putting this one in the pom file but it took a day or two to allow me to use its methods.  So I assumed it got removed lol.  All good now

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough in basic cases

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt((jwt) -> {}));

        // State-less session (state in access-token only)
        http.sessionManagement(sm -> sm.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));

        // Disable CSRF because of state-less session-management
        http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable());

        // Return 401 (unauthorized) instead of 302 (redirect to login) when
        // authorization is missing or invalid
        http.exceptionHandling(eh -> eh.authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, authException) -> {
            response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.WWW_AUTHENTICATE, "Basic realm=\"Restricted Content\"");
            response.sendError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.getReasonPhrase());
        }));

        http.authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
            .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/public/**")).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated());

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

For more details, start [there](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#oauth_essentials).